# Equation solution to absolute value in wolfram is different

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, absolute-value, wolfram-alpha

The goal is to find the solution to the equation:
log(|(x^2 - x - 1) / (x^2 + x - 2)|) = 0
where log is the common logarithm.
I get x = 1/2, ±√(3/2)
Wolfram gets something much more complicated:
[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=log%28%7C%28x%5E2%20-%20x%20-%201%29%20%2F%20%28x%5E2%20%2B%20x%20-%202%29%7C%29&assumption=%7B%22FunClash%22%2C%20%22log%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Log10%22%7D)

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't know why Wolfram didn't get the $\pm\sqrt{\frac 32}$ (the other roots were the non-real roots).  I suspect in may have had something to do with how Wolfram rounds.  $\pm \sqrt {\frac 32}$ are the endpoints of the domain and maybe Wolfram had some weird rounding error.

Comment: The reason why WA gives all those complex roots is probably that it's trying to solve the equation $\log\left\lvert\frac{z^2-z-1}{z^2+z+2}\right\rvert=0$ for $z\in\Bbb C$, and of course $\left\lvert\frac{z^2-z-1}{z^2+z+2}\right\rvert=1$ has many more roots than the equation $\frac{z^2-z-1}{z^2+z+2}=\pm1$. It probably has not realized that the ones with $n\in (2\Bbb Z+1)\pi$ are real.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio and how do I solve for those additional roots in this case?

Comment: @GeorgeXavier You solve $\frac{z^2-z-1}{z^2+z-2}=\omega$, where $\omega$ is a complex number of modulus $1$.

Comment: You can specify the domain to recover the other real solutions, e.g. ["solve log(...) = 0 over the reals"](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=solve+log%28%7C%28x%5E2+-+x+-+1%29+%2F+%28x%5E2+%2B+x+-+2%29%7C%29+%3D+0+over+reals)

Comment: Actually, "completing" WA's list of real solutions is as simple as including the string ["solve"](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=solve+log+%7C%28x%5E2+-+x+-+1%29+%2F+%28x%5E2+%2B+x+-+2%29%7C+%3D+0) in the input...